# Fetching a key of a current value from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have this simple Firebase Realtime Database:

[image]

and I have the `inner Id` (in blue), How Can I Fetch the `key` (in red) using ReactJS?

I've already read the [Firebase Realtime Database Docs (Modular SDK v9)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_5) but I did not see a way to do so. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic code if you want to get the whole list for ID 1 would look like this:

```js
import { getDatabase, get, ref } from "firebase/database";

const getData = async () => {
  const db = getDatabase();
  const snap = await get(ref(db, `Lists/${id1}`));

  snap.forEach((r) => {
    console.log("key", r.key);
    console.log("value", r.val()); // red
    console.log("id", r.val()["id"]); // blue
  });
};
```